# Help with Jquery onchange navigation please

Tags: jquery, managed-navigation

EDIT: So this was fixed after obtaining the correct source for my JQuery (the site was trying to play around with it for some reason) and by locating the actual page for the form that is appearing in the iFrame `/NewForm.aspx` and placing Daniel's code in there. Thank you so much for all of your help Daniel Stölzner, you have been beyond helpful.

What I ended up with:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
var select = $j("#ctl00_m_g_7bb989f2_7ca9_456f_b0be_ee0996c38db1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup")
    select.on("change", function() {
        if (select.find("option:selected").val() == "19") {
            window.location = "http://MYOTHERSITEs/NewForm.aspx"
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

Original question (incorrect workings removed):-
Hi I have a drop down selection in a bubble form for a NewsGator Idea Stream. For business reasons I am not allowed to completely rebuild the site.

This drop down has 15 selections and the form is perfect for 14 of them, the other single selection (PPI) needs additional information. Now I am looking for a simple navigation to another existing site when they choose this single option (i am using workflow solutions to complete this list anyway). I haven't used Jquery before so I'm stuck even trying to trawl through tutorials.

The HTML element can be found below, it is `<option value="19">PPI</option>` that I am looking to navigate elsewhere on change.

```
<select name="ctl00$m$g_7bb989f2_7ca9_456f_b0be_ee0996c38db1$ctl00$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_m_g_7bb989f2_7ca9_456f_b0be_ee0996c38db1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup" title="Category">
                <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
                <option value="6">O1</option>
                <option value="7">O2</option>
                <option value="8">O3</option>
                <option value="9">O4</option>
                <option value="10">O5</option>
                <option value="11">O6</option>
                <option value="12">O7</option>
                <option value="13">O8</option>
                <option value="14">O9</option>
                <option value="15">O10</option>
                <option value="16">O11</option>
                <option value="17">O12</option>
                <option value="18">O13</option>
                <option value="19">PPI</option>
                <option value="20">O15</option>

            </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var select = $j("#ctl00_m_g_7bb989f2_7ca9_456f_b0be_ee0996c38db1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup")
    select.on("change", function() {
        if (select.find("option:selected").val() == "19") {
            window.location = "http://MYOTHERSITEs/NewForm.aspx"
        }
    })
})
</script>

<select name="ctl00$m$g_7bb989f2_7ca9_456f_b0be_ee0996c38db1$ctl00$ctl05$ctl03$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$Lookup" id="ctl00_m_g_7bb989f2_7ca9_456f_b0be_ee0996c38db1_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup" title="Category">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option>
    <option value="6">O1</option>
    <option value="7">O2</option>
    <option value="8">O3</option>
    <option value="9">O4</option>
    <option value="10">O5</option>
    <option value="11">O6</option>
    <option value="12">O7</option>
    <option value="13">O8</option>
    <option value="14">O9</option>
    <option value="15">O10</option>
    <option value="16">O11</option>
    <option value="17">O12</option>
    <option value="18">O13</option>
    <option value="19">PPI</option>
    <option value="20">O15</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get nothing.

Comment: Any error messages in the console? Do you have Minimal Download Strategy activated?

Comment: Hi I haven't turned on any features at all... I was getting confused by different tutorials for JQuery on SP. I only started using SP last week so not familiar with it's console unfortunately. Took me the week to get my head around workflows and general functionality; I'm a database guy really, apart from the occasional web scrape with VBA this SP web stuff is alien to me.

Comment: Okay, I'm using Sharepoint 2010, Google tells me Minimal Download Strategy is 2013...

Comment: The console I'm talking about is the console of your browser. When you hit F12 there should be a tab called Console at  the bottom of your screen. JavaScript errors are shown there. Please check if there are any errors.

Comment: GET http://thissite/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-3.1.0.min.js

Comment: sp.ui.rte.js?rev=XV1%2B0hMQYgNFbWCOzqey2g%3D%3D:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null

Comment: scs.webtrends.com/dcswoov9k9dv0houkjshd3x0n_6z4w/dcs.gif?&dcsdat=1473760741…list_item_action=NewItem&WT.shp_list=Ideas&WT.shp_list_item=New%2520Item:1 GET https://scs.webtrends.com/dcswoov9k9dv0houkjshd3x0n_6z4w/dcs.gif?&dcsdat=14…p_list_item_action=NewItem&WT.shp_list=Ideas&WT.shp_list_item=New%2520Item net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: those are the three errors i get, sorry for being useless...

Comment: I have used an alert to ensure that my references are valid.

Comment: And if I use the google library: `Home.aspx:881 GET http://businessmainsite/sites/sme/IdeaTest/SitePages/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.j%E2%80%8Bs 
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:6 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active`

Comment: I made a change to my answer. It now includes the complete HTML and script. Please check if that works. This whole snippet placed in a CEWP works right away.

Comment: Wow, almost there now then. that works by creating the selection menu within that web part. Now if I want that to act on the form for my list (which opens as a bubble thanks to NewsGator idea stream) is this achievable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45307/discussion-between-daniel-stolzner-and-glitch-doctor).